# App engine subdomain mapping to a specific service

Tags: angular, go, google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

I have an angular-go application.
I want to deploy it using app engine.

my angular service is the default service so I am able to access it using

```
domain.org/
```

I now want to access a user service api using

```
user.domain.org/api/user
```

I added the subdomain to my app engine project and `dispatch.yaml` file that has the contents

```
dispatch:
   - url: "domain.org/*"
     service: default

   - url: "user.domain.org/*"
     service: user
```

But I am unable to hit the api using

```
domain.org/api/user
```

However, I am able to access the api using

```
user-dot-projectID.uc.r.appspot.com/api/user
```

how do I access this api using my own domain name `domain.org`

```
user.domain.org/api/user
```

Answer (score 2):

In the question, you didn't indicate whether you have added a `CNAME` record on your domain registrar for your subdomain pointing to `ghs.googlehosted.com`. You should have a `CNAME` record for `user.domain.org` and any other subdomain you intend to use with `google-app-engine` pointing to `ghs.googlehosted.com`. Then add a custom domain name record for the subdomain to your app engine. Follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/mapping-custom-domains) to add the custom domain names.